# React & Mobx .map() not working on onChange

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mobx

I have two rendered inputs defined in `options:[1,2]` in mobx store. On change I'm trying to make it so the values are passed to the `values:["",""]` array.

Loading the app works, but on `onChange` it gives an:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at PollOptions.render (PollOptions.js:28)
```

Can you help me understand why isn't it working? Everything worked fine when it was on the component state.

PollOptions.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";

import "./PollOptions.css";

@inject("newPollStore")
@observer
class PollOptions extends Component {
  state = {};

  closeResetHandler = () => {
    this.props.newPollStore.setIsVisible(false);
    //reset form
  };

  changeHandler = (i, el) => {
    //setform in state of mobx store
    console.log(el.target.value);
    const currentValue = [...this.props.newPollStore.newPollState];
    console.log(currentValue);
    currentValue[i] = el.target.value;
    console.log({currentValue});
    this.props.newPollStore.setPollState({currentValue});
    console.log(this.props.newPollStore.newPollState)
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.props.newPollStore.newPollState.options.map(
      (i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <input
              className="option"
              type="text"
              required={i === 0 || i === 1}
              placeholder={`Option #${i + 1}..`}
              onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this,i)}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    );
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="newPollSpan" onClick={this.closeResetHandler}>
          X
        </span>
        {options}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default PollOptions;
```

newPollStore.js:

```
import { action, observable } from "mobx";

class authStore {
  @observable newPollState = {
    values: ["", ""],
    options: [1, 2]
  };
  @observable newPollDivVisible = false;

  @action setPollState = (obj) => {
    this.newPollState = obj;
  };
  @action setIsVisible = bool => {
    this.newPollDivVisible = bool;
  };
}

export default new authStore();
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since MobX works with mutability, you can just set the value in the array with the same index as the changed input.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/62v8l4q253))**

```
@inject("newPollStore")
@observer
class PollOptions extends Component {
  // ...

  changeHandler = (i, el) => {
    this.props.newPollStore.newPollState.options[i] = el.target.value;
  };

  render() {
    const options = this.props.newPollStore.newPollState.options.map((option, index) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <input
            className="option"
            type="text"
            required={option === 0 || option === 1}
            placeholder={`Option #${option}..`}
            onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this, index)}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="newPollSpan" onClick={this.closeResetHandler}>
          X
        </span>
        {options}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```